# Unfriendly numbers c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is a problem on interviewstreet called UnfriendlyNumbers. The problem goes like this -

There is one friendly number and N unfriendly numbers. We want to find how many numbers are there which exactly divide the friendly number, but does not divide any of the unfriendly numbers.
Sample Input:
8 16
2 5 7 4 3 8 3 18
Sample Output:
1

All the testcases that I can imagine execute correctly, but for some reason, the website deems it incorrect for a set of testcases. Do you guys see any errors in the code/logic?

```
void get_factors(unsigned long n, vector<unsigned long> &factors)
{
    unsigned long sqrt = pow(n, 0.5);
    for (unsigned long i = 1; i < sqrt; i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            factors.push_back(i);
            factors.push_back(n/i);
        }
    }
    if (n%sqrt == 0) {
        factors.push_back(sqrt);
    }
}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int n; 
    unsigned long k, j;
    cin >> n >> k;

    if (n == 0 || k == 0) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    set<unsigned long> unfriendly;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> j;
        unfriendly.insert(j);
    }

    vector<unsigned long> factors;
    get_factors(k, factors);

    unsigned int count = factors.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < factors.size(); i++) {
        for (set<unsigned long>::iterator it = unfriendly.lower_bound(factors[i]); 
             it !=  unfriendly.end();
             it++)
        {
            if (*it % factors[i] == 0) {
                count--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << count;
}
```

Comment: I'd replace `i = 1; i < sqrt` with `i = 1; i <= sqrt` so that you can get rid of your second `if` statement. Also, are those failed cases specified?

Comment: No, it doesn't specify the failed testcases

Comment: @Blender, when `n == 16`, for example, that would cause `4` to get counted twice.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4):

Your `get_factors` is incorrect. For numbers like 30 or 35, some divisors are omitted.

`sqrt` is the largest integer not exceeding the square root, but when `n == sqrt*(sqrt+1)` or `n == sqrt*(sqrt+2)`, you don't record `sqrt+1` resp. `sqrt+2` as divisors.

Also, there is the possibility that

```
unsigned long sqrt = pow(n, 0.5);
```

can yield a wrong result if `n` is sufficiently large, better adjust it

```
while(sqrt > n/sqrt) --sqrt;
while(sqrt+1 <= n/(sqrt+1)) ++sqrt;
```

And, it may be that `unsigned long` isn't large enough, for safety use `unsigned long long`.

Apart from that, the only thing I see that could fail is if any of the numbers is 0.

```
    for (set<unsigned long>::iterator it = unfriendly.lower_bound(factors[i]); 
         it !=  unfriendly.end();
         it++)
```

will fail if an unfriendly number is 0; and if the friendly number is 0, all bets are off (the answer is then 0 if any unfriendly number is 0, infinity otherwise).

Comment: Fixed the get_factors bug (Thanks Daniel).
Now the algorithm finds the solution, but it isn't fast enough. The contraints are that the number n and k are of the order 10^18 and 10^13 respectively, and the code in c++ should solve it in < 3 seconds.

I improved the algorithm further. I start from the largest element in the factors set.
Whenever, I find a number from the factors_set that divides an unfriendly number, I remove that number and all its factors from the factors_set. Still not fast enough! Any other ideas for improvements in the algorithm?

Comment: If you determine the divisors of `n` your way, where `n` is about 10^18, you need about 10^9 divisions. That takes something like 5 seconds on my box. Typically the testing machines for online judges are slower. So the first thing to optimise is the `get_factors` method. If `n` has only few divisors, more elaborate algorithms are needed, but typically obtaining the prime factorisation of `n` by trial division should be fast enough (if `p <= q` are the two largest prime factors of `n`, you need to divide to `max(p,sqrt(q))`). From that, construct the divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Get the common divisors between the unfriendly numbers and the friendly number K using GCD. O(N)

Then get the divisors of K in O(sqrt(K)).

Loop the cmn_div and div of k, to get the answer in O(N*sqrt(K))